# How to navigate to a fragment from Notification? Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

On getting notification i wanted to open my application and navigate to Details fragment since i am using Navigation Component from jetpack, but i dont know how to implement it?

here is my notification service code

```
val intent = Intent(this, DetailedFragment::class.java) 

    val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "100")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setContentTitle(rm.data["title"])
        .setContentText(rm.data["body"])
        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
        .setCustomContentView(nmrv)
        .setCustomBigContentView(exrv)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())

    val manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(100, builder.build())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#explicit):

> An explicit deep link is a single instance of a deep link that uses a `PendingIntent` to take users to a specific location within your app. You might surface an explicit deep link as part of a notification or an app widget, for example.

> You can use the [`NavDeepLinkBuilder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavDeepLinkBuilder) class to construct a `PendingIntent`

```
val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
    .setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
    .setDestination(R.id.android)
    .setArguments(args)
    .createPendingIntent()
```

With that `PendingIntent`, you can attach it to your notification by using `setContentIntent()`:

```
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```